# SD Card not returning response after CMD17 (read single block)

Tags: sd-card

I have multiple 512MB SDSC cards that seem to block after getting a read single block command. I get back the expected data which I wrote before, but the card seems to stop returning anything but 0xFF afterwards. Even simple commands like CMD13 (request status) do not send back anything but 0xFF. While these commands did return normal before the read command was used.

The entire code does work with another SDHC card. Attempting reinitialization does not work until the card has had its power removed. I am using SPI mode.

I am running out of ideas what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0):

The addressing scheme for SDHC and SDSC is slightly different: SDHC requires SECTOR id while SDSC needs BYTE address. Maybe that's the case with CMD17.